# IP Forwarding Fails Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: ufw, ip-forward

Running 2 servers in VirtualBox.
Server 1 (will be the firewall)

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forwward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

Anywhere on enp0s3         ALLOW FWD   Anywhere on enp0s8
Anywhere on enp0s8         ALLOW FWD   Anywhere on enp0s3
Anywhere (v6) on enp0s3    ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6) on enp0s8
Anywhere (v6) on enp0s8    ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6) on enp0s3
```

Server 2 (will be web server):

```
$ sudo ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp0s3
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1

$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Server 2 can ping both internal and external IP addresses of the firewall.

Comment: Both servers appear to have the same IP address: 192.168.0.1.

Comment: No, server 1 is 192.168.0.2 1nd server 2 is 192.168.0.1

Comment: OK, the other way around then. But if server 1 is the gateway at `192.168.0.2`, then why doesn't server 2 have it as its gateway? Its default gateway is `192.168.0.1`, which is ... itself?

Comment: No, that's right.  We're telling server 2, "For your default route, use the interface with the address 192.168.0.1", which is it's only interface, so that makes sense.